# How to insert answer into "Answer" table

Tags: php, mysqli

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ybZvv/57/

I have a fiddle here where the user can append row and select answers for each row. To use the fiddle please follow steps below:

1. When you open the fiddle, click on the "Add Question" button
   twice. This will append two rows underneath.
2. In first row select buttons A and B, these buttons will turn green
   and underneath you will see the text input values of these selected
   buttons.
3. In second row select buttons A, C and E, these buttons will turn
   green and underneath you will see the text input values of these
   selected buttons.

Now what I want to do is that for each answer in each row, they will contain it's own "AnswerId" and the answers will be inserted into the "Answer" column in the "Answer" table.

Below is what the table should look like following the jsfiddle answers:

Answer Table

```
AnswerId (auto)    Answer
5                   AB
6                   ACE
```

The only problem I am getting with the above table is that it is not inserting the answers unser the "Answer" column.

Then I want to store the "AnswerId" from the "Answer" Table in the "Question" table. So as I have appended 2 rows, the "QuestionId" is 1 and 2 and below is what the "Question" Table should look like:

Question Table

```
QuestionId    AnswerId
1               5
2               6
```

The above table is working fine.

Below is the error I am recieving:

- Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /web/stud/QandATable3.php on line 172

My question is that by looking at the code below, how can the above error be fixed so that it is able to INSERT the answer under the "Answer" column?

Below is the php/mysqli code (I have commented the line where the error is occuring):

```
    $i = 0;
    $c = count($_POST['gridValues']); //Counts each appended row which works

    for($i = 0;  $i < $c; $i++ ){

 $selected_answer = $_POST['value'];


     $answersql = "INSERT INTO Answer (Answer) 
        VALUES (?)";

          if (!$insertanswer = $mysqli->prepare($answersql)) {
          // Handle errors with prepare operation here
        }  

        $insertanswer->bind_param("s", $selected_answer);

            $insertanswer->execute();

            if ($insertanswer->errno) {
              // Handle query error here
            }

            $insertanswer->close();

            $lastID = $mysqli->insert_id;

    $questionsql = "INSERT INTO Question (QuestionId, AnswerId) 
        VALUES (?, ?)";


        if (!$insert = $mysqli->prepare($questionsql)) {
          // Handle errors with prepare operation here
        }

    $insert->bind_param("ii", $_POST['numQuestion'][$i],  $lastID);

            $insert->execute();

            if ($insert->errno) {
              // Handle query error here
            }

            $insert->close();

    }

    ?>
```

Below is the code where it successfully appends a question number for each row:

```
var qnum = 1;

var $qid = $("<td class='qid'></td>").text(qnum);

          $('.num_questions').each( function() {

    var $this = $(this);

     var $questionNumber = $("<input type='hidden' class='num_questionsRow'>").attr('name',$this.attr('name')+"[]")
                   .attr('value',$this.val());

     $qid.append($questionNumber);                             

    ++qnum;    
    $(".questionNum").text(qnum);
    $(".num_questions").val(qnum);

 $tr.append($qid);
```

Comment: There is no mention of `gridValues` in the Fiddle. Where is that defined?

Comment: Also, based on your Fiddle, your PHP code won't even receive the correct information. If a user selected AB in question 1 and ACE in question 2, the `value` item in the `$_POST` array will only contain 4 items as opposed to 5, because the same input name — `value[answerARow]` — is used in both questions. I suggest you rewrite your HTML/JavaScript first.

Comment: @andrewap gridvalues I did not include in the fiddle but it is in my main application. When you say rewirte my html and javascript, can you tell me what I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see issues on both client- and server-sides. I'll first address the client-side issues.

The input fields you create have names in the format: `value[answerXRow]`, where `X` is the selected answer character. If the user selects the same character across multiple answers, there will be multiple input fields with the same name (e.g. two `value[answerARow]` fields based on your instructions). Moreover, there is no way for your PHP code to tell the difference between which `value` is for which question, because they will all be submitted in the same `value` array.

My suggestion is to use a multi-dimensional array in this format: `value[n][]`, where `n` is the question number. With this new setup, you should end up with the following input fields:

```
<input type="hidden" value="A" name="value[1][]">
<input type="hidden" value="B" name="value[1][]">
<input type="hidden" value="A" name="value[2][]">
<input type="hidden" value="C" name="value[2][]">
<input type="hidden" value="E" name="value[2][]">
```

Note that the selected value is encoded in the `value` attribute. The `name` attribute only contains the question to which the value belongs.

Now, on the server-side, you'll need to iterate over the `$_POST['value']` array:

```
// $questionNumber is simply n in value[n][]
// $answers is an array of value attributes from <input>s for this question

foreach ($_POST['value'] as $questionNumber => $answers) {
    // combine all the answers into a single string (e.g. ACE)
    $selected_answer = implode('', $answers);

    // continue onto inserting rows into the Answer and Questions tables
    // ...
}
```

Comment: That is a good idea, I will give it a go, I never really done multi-dimensional arrays before but I will give it ago. AM I ok to post the code in my question on how I append the question number for each row, it is just that if you see it then I am hoping you can help me in stating which variable will replace 'n' in the array

Comment: I will include it in fiddle as well, give me 2 mins

Comment: Fiddle is updated showing question numbers for each appended row

Comment: You should use `iQuestionIndex` for `n`. You don't need to put the selected value `X` in the `name` attribute at all, because that information is already stated in the `value` attribute.

Comment: So just to make sure, I simply just need to change: `.attr('name', "value[" + $this.attr('id') + "]")` to `.attr('name', "value[" + iQuestionIndex + "][" + $this.attr('id') + "]")`? Are you sure it isn't `gQuestionIndex`?

Comment: It should be `.attr('name', "value[" + iQuestionIndex + "][]")`, because you *don't need to put the selected value `X` in the `name` attribute*. And I think `gQuestionIndex` and `iQuestionIndex` are the same thing in your code.

Comment: Yeah they are the same thing lol. I just refreshed the page and I just saw your huge answer lol. I just like to say thanks you for your help, this was a huge amount of help. Thank you very much andrew :) Really appreciate it. Upvote and best answer

Answer (score 1):

You're taking the values like they'e being posted as an array and they won't be, var_dump out the $_POST values to see what it's actually returning.

For the record, that code is an absolute mess. I'm not trying to be mean here, but your JS allows multiple answers to the same question. The select in the PHP is an utter waste and that entire section could be replaced with:

```
$selected_answer = $_POST['value'];
```

You're running a select to set the variable to the post value anyway...

Comment: Should it be '$selected_answer = $_POST['value'];' or '$selected_answer = $_POST['value'][$i];' Btw I know my code is a mess, I am not really a web programmer, I'm more of a database programmer. Also I do want multiple answers for a question (Well my supervisor wanted that lol)

Comment: Also when you said the select is an utter waste, are you meaning that I should just get rid of the switch statement?

Comment: Depends on how the form is actually posting the data. I doubt it's posting it back in an array which is what $_POST['value'][$i] is, that is iterating through an array and not just normal post data. Put var_dump($_POST); at the top of the PHP your form is submitting to so you can actually see what the variables are that it's returning.  And yes, the switch is doing absolutely nothing. You're checking to see if something = A to set something else to A. Just set something to something else if you catch my drift.

Comment: When I perform the var_dump($_POST), it outputs this: `array(2) {  ["numQuestion"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "2" }   ["submitDetails"]=> string(14) "Submit Details" ["value"]=> array(4) { ["answerARow"]=> string(1) "A" ["answerBRow"]=> string(1) "B" ["answerCRow"]=> string(1) "C" ["answerERow"]=> string(1) "E" } } Notice: Array to string conversion in /..../ on line 234 Notice: Array to string conversion in /.../ on line 234.` The line this is pointing to is this `$insertanswer->execute();` I can see that coz AnswerA is in both questions, that it only inserts one of them